# Configure CPAN to Run Author Tests As Well

Tags: perl, cpan

Is it possible to configure CPAN to run author tests as well if they are appropriate for my OS/Arch? I am more concerned about installing a package that is out of sync with its own test suite without realizing it than taking more time to install new packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Author tests" are usually run or skipped based on an env var, so it's just a question of setting that env var. For example, I use `DEVEL_TESTS`, so the following would run all of [WWW-Kickstarter](http://search.cpan.org/dists/WWW-Kickstarter/)'s tests, including the one that makes sure all references to the distro's version are consistent:

```
DEVEL_TESTS=1 cpan WWW::Kickstarter
```

Comment: Is it common to use that particular environment variable? Also your link is broken (I think you changed dist to dists). Did you mean http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Kickstarter/?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Lancaster Consensus](https://github.com/Perl-Toolchain-Gang/toolchain-site/blob/master/lancaster-consensus.md) `AUTHOR_TESTING` is the env var that distribution authors should be using for this kind of testing.  In practice, there are other var names out in the wild, but people should probably standardize on this one.

```
AUTHOR_TESTING=1 cpan Module::NAME
```

Comment: Why does the article recommend that CPAN clients not set `AUTHOR_TESTING` or `RELEASE_TESTING`? Do authors commonly make tests that require nontrivial input from the user?

Comment: There are lots of reasons not to run author tests on clients.  Take, for example, the cases of checking for Pod errors, Pod coverage, spelling tests or something that checks for a well formed distribution (ie that certain files exist).  There's really no need to run these sorts of tests on clients.  You just introduce more dependencies, a longer test run and perhaps even some new, interesting test failures. You do, however, want to run them locally just before you cut a new release to ensure that you have a sane release.  So you mark them to run as author tests.